# How do I know if my dell laptop has a camera?

Tags: webcam

When I make a video call, I can see the person I call, but they cant see me. I have an eye on the top of the screen. Is this the camera? How do I activate it? How do I know the model # if needed?

Comment: How are we supposed to know without knowing which laptop you are using(make/model)?

Comment: Hit Win-key and type `devmgmt.msc`. This applet will show you all devices on your Windows pc. Look for `imaging devices`, there should be your webcam, if it's drivers are installed. Which video calling app are you trying to use?

Comment: RogUE: What a stupid comment. Notice that others were able to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you arent sure on which model of Dell laptop you have, you can find out byrunning  the following command in PowerShell:

```
 (gwmi win32_bios).SerialNumber
```

This will give you your computers service tag.  You can then go to the dell support website (http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukdhs1) and enter the serive tag about half way down the webpage in the "`Enter a Service Tag or Express Service Code.`" box.  Alternatively, you can use the detect product function within the website to find out your model number - but personally, I try not to let anythign external have access to my machines unless needed.

Once you have given the site your service tag, it will tell you which model you have.  You can then google specifications for that model and see if it is indeed a camera.

If it is a camera, you will need to install the drivers.  Again, return to the dell support site, enter a service tag, go to the "`Drivers and Downloads`" section, pcik your OS and then download and install their webcam drivers and application suite.

Once this is done, reboot your computer and you should be able to use your webcam for video calls.

You may also find that you need to configure your webcam for use with certain applications such as Skype.  Most webcall software does provide support articles on how to configure a webcam for use with their software.  As Skype is (arguably) the most popular VOIP (Voice Over Internet Protocol) service, [here'a a link](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34440/how-do-i-use-a-webcam-with-skype) to their article on configuring a webcam for their software.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have any built-in webcam you should see it physically on your laptop screen. And also you can verify it from your device manager in windows.

Also, you may use a web browser to browse to Dell's support website (http://support.dell.com/) and search for the specification of your laptop.

Hope it helps.